# Layout like HotStar App

Tags: android, json, layout, android-recyclerview

I have to create layout like `HotStar` App, but I am bit confuse that what would be the `best way` of doing this:

[image]

1. Do I need multiple RecyclerViews or single RecyclerView is enough ?
2. Do I need to call multiple JSONs or single JSON is enough to fetch
   data from server?
3. How Do I use different - different layouts for You May Also Like and
   Must Watch Clips

Comment: Use a recyclerview with GridLayoutManager. A single JSON response is enough if you format it correctly

Comment: Can I have a Layout Example ?

Comment: Layout Example : One ImageView and two TextViews in vertical LinearLayout or CardView and inflate that layout in Adapter of RecyclerView, that's all.

Comment: @Apurva I mean How Do I use different - different layouts for You May Also Like and Must Watch Clips

Comment: There's one method called `getItemViewType()` in RecyclerView's Adapter, you can override that method and can inflate different layouts as per your need. Open this link to learn how to inflate different views in RecyclerView http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type

Comment: @Apurva ok got it. I think you already experienced with same, share your github demo repo with me...

Comment: @Sophie: see following example :https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/e81e126227f8a4bb339c

Comment: I don't have any repo for that example and you won't even need it. There are few steps to finish your task : just create recyclerview and different layouts and then inflate them as per your need.

Comment: @Apurva so finally my JSON should look like this: http://pastebin.com/hLqE6j7t

Comment: You just need one field in your json response to distinguish the data, whether it's of type 1 or type 2. Since you're already getting titles *You May Also Like* and *Must Watch Clips* in your response, you can distinguish the data and based on that you can set it in different layouts.

Comment: @Apurva I tried but did not any success, can you provide a demo code... ?

Comment: what have you done till now ?

Comment: @Sophie I have posted some logic detail try it

Answer (score 12):

With this you will be able to create same Look-And-Feel

**1.-** For upper menu tab, you have to layout [TABS](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html)

**2.-** For detail section, please add [CARDS](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/cards.html#)

**3.-** Divider for your sections, use [SUBHEADERS](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/subheaders.html#subheaders-list-subheaders)

**Now, regarding your questions:**

**1.** You can handle everything with just one single RecyclerViews

**2.** Best approach, is to get a separated JSON for each section, since you never know how big each section will be. That will help a lot with a better performance and clean code.

**

### NEW UPDATE

**

***Your Main Layout Activity***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.alphasystech.hotvideos.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <include
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                layout="@layout/toolbar_layout">

            </include>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabStyle">
            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/viewPager">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

***Your Home Fragment Layout (Also you can clone this for MOVIES, SPORTS...)***

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeFragment">

<!-- A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes -->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/home_recyclerview"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

***Your Cards Layout for your Home Fragment(Also you can clone this for MOVIES, SPORTS...)***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#81C784"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="4dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/item_image"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/item_title"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_image"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/item_detail"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_image"
            android:layout_below="@+id/item_title"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: screenshot sample]

I think, the above sample will give you a good direction :)

Comment: What about if I want to add movable buttons? I mean if user scroll the view up-and-down?

Comment: It's really simple, if you use Floating Action Buttons https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html

Comment: Can you share an xml script with me, where I can get some Idea how to show data in single recyclerview from different - different jsons ? or If possible so could you write share a small demo to achieve that...

Comment: Please, take a look at my UPDATED post. I am giving you the xmls sample.

Comment: How can we achieve it with single recycler view? lets say we have a recycler view with vertical scroll as a parent, then for each row of items we need another recycler view with horizontal scroll (LinearLayoutManager) right? If so there will be a total of (no of categories + parent) recycler views right?.
If we put everything inside a single grid recycler view how will be achieve individual horizontal scroll?

Answer (score 5):

> 1. Do I need multiple RecyclerViews or single RecyclerView is enough?

Single `RecyclerView` is enough.

> 2. Do I need to call multiple JSONs or single JSON is enough to fetch data from server?

Single `JSON` response is enough.

> 3. How Do I use different - different layouts for You May Also Like and Must Watch Clips

Make this part of UI as `RecyclerView` row.

[image: RecyclerView row]

This is the simplest solution if you known max number of items in row. Your model need to have each row data.

Row layout xml example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ddd"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:text="You May Also Like"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:text="MORE" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">


        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/item1_CV"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/item1_image"
                        android:background="#fff"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="8dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/item1_title"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Mere Rang Mein"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/item1_subTitle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="Romance, Hindi, Life OK"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/item1_image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:background="#FF78aa" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/item2_CV"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/item2_image"
                        android:background="#fff"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="8dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/item2_title"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Mere Rang Mein"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/item2_subTitle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="Romance, Hindi, Life OK"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/item2_image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:background="#FF78aa" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/item3_CV"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/item3_image"
                        android:background="#fff"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="8dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/item3_title"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Mere Rang Mein"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/item3_subTitle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="Romance, Hindi, Life OK"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/item3_image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:background="#FF78aa" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/item4_CV"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/item4_image"
                        android:background="#fff"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="8dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/item4_title"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Mere Rang Mein"
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/item4_subTitle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="Romance, Hindi, Life OK"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/item4_image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:background="#FF78aa" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Result:
[image: Row layout result]

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Do I need multiple RecyclerViews or single RecyclerView is enough ?

Single Recyclerview with GridLayoutManager is enough for this purpose.

> 2. Do I need to call multiple JSONs or single JSON is enough to fetch data from server?

Single JSON response will fulfill your job.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this just laying out first the TABS and display your CARDS inside of a ViewPager.

Something like this....

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments...
```

Answer (score 3):

> Q1. Do I need multiple RecyclerViews or single RecyclerView is enough?

In HotStar App there are two scrollings:

1. Main layout - Vertical scrolling
2. Each section - Horizontal scrolling

If you want the same, you have to use two `RecyclerView`, one for each.
If you want only vertical scrolling, then one is more than enough.

> Q2. Do I need to call multiple JSONs or single JSON is enough to fetch
>   data from server?

Use splash screen and call single `JSON`, then on tab click parse particular `JSON` for clicked tab.

**Note**: If you feel it takes too much time, then do separate call for each tab.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Do I need multiple RecyclerViews or single RecyclerView is enough?
```

single RecyclerView.

```
    Do I need to call multiple JSONs or single JSON is enough to fetch data from server?
```

single JSON data from server will do your job.

```
    How Do I use different - different layouts for You May Also Like and Must Watch Clips
```

use recyclerview with multiple view type

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    class ViewHolder0 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...
    }

    class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // Just as an example, return 0 or 2 depending on position
        // Note that unlike in ListView adapters, types don't have to be contiguous
        return position % 2 * 2;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         switch (viewType) {
             case 0: return new ViewHolder0(...);
             case 2: return new ViewHolder2(...);
             ...
         }
    }
}
```

Use RecyclerView with header and normal item type

Answer (score 2):

Use this as your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tag="iv"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            style="@style/bold" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/TabLayoutStyle"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabStyle"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

- The `CoordinatorLayout`+`AppBarLayout` will make the toolbar scroll up as you scroll your layout
- Create a fragment for pages in your ViewPager and write a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` for it
- Don't forget to call tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager) to inflate the `TabLayout`
- See [this](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) for an example project
- Inside your fragment, use a `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` and spanCount `2`
- Inside your `RecyclerView.Adapter` implementation, use `getItemViewType` to specify number of view types you want. In the screenshot it looks like you only have 2 types (or 3 if you want the video tile to be a separate viewtype. Note that you can still use same layout for different view types, just hide/show the views you want in each view holder. This will reduce layout duplicacy). [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type) to know how to make one.
- Use [`CardView`](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) to make the the image card
- Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), or [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco) to load images inside those Cards (Picasso and Glide are easier to use compared to Fresco but fresco is better with memory)

> Do I need to call multiple JSONs or single JSON is enough to fetch data from server?

That completely depends on you, you can go either way, however getting all data in single request will make fetching faster.

PS: You can use GSON to parse your Json and keep yourself a little sane

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need multiple RecyclerViews or single RecyclerView is enough ?

A single one is enough.

> Do I need to call multiple JSONs or single JSON is enough to fetch
>   data from server?

A single JSON is enough.

> How Do I use different - different layouts for You May Also Like and
>   Must Watch Clips

- 1 single layout for the section headers, as they look the same
- 1 layout for "You May Also Like" items
- 1 layout for "Must Watch Clips" items, because they are different: they have the "minutes" label and the "play" button. You could use the same layout and hide these views when not needed, it's up to you

With the library [SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter) you can add different "sections" to your RecyclerView, each section can have its own header, like on the image below:

[image: Grid Section with Header]

You need to create your "section" classes:

```
class MustWatchClipsSection extends StatelessSection {

    String title;
    List<Clip> clipList;

    public MustWatchClipsSection(String title, List<Clip> clipList) {
        // call constructor with layout resources for this Section header, footer and items 
        super(R.layout.section_header, R.layout.section_footer,  R.layout.section_item);

        this.title = title;
        this.clipList = clipList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getContentItemsTotal() {
        return clipList.size(); // number of items of this section
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
        // return a custom instance of ViewHolder for the items of this section
        return new MyItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyItemViewHolder itemHolder = (MyItemViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your view here
        itemHolder.tvItem.setText(clipList.get(position).getName());
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getHeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        return new SimpleHeaderViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        MyHeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (MyHeaderViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your header view here
        headerHolder.tvItem.setText(date);
    }
}
```

Then you set up the RecyclerView with your sections:

```
// Create an instance of SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter 
SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();

MayAlsoLikeSection mySection1 = new MayAlsoLikeSection("You May Also Like", mediaList);
MustWatchClipsSection mySection2 = new MustWatchClipsSection("Must Watch Clips", clipList);

// Add your Sections
sectionAdapter.addSection(mySection1);
sectionAdapter.addSection(mySection2);

// Set up your RecyclerView with the SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
glm.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        switch(sectionAdapter.getSectionItemViewType(position)) {
            case SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_HEADER:
                return 2;
            default:
                return 1;
        }
    }
});
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(glm);
recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```

You can see the full code [here](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/github/luizgrp/sectionedrecyclerviewadapter/demo/Example5Fragment.java), layouts are also available in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you not need to use multiple recycler view or Layout**

You can just make logic in recycler view on position of item.
like if first item don't have play button and text view of time then you can just make by default its visibility gone and when you need that play button and time text view in that position you can make it visible.

for example you have video layout in second position then in get view method you get Position in that you can make logic of this to visible.

I have just create custom listview row for it now what ever you want you  can  do with this logic and no need to make multiple layout also.

**Try this logic hope its help you**